# Getting a constant from a GLSL shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, constants, shader

I have a shader written in GLSL with an array of structs for holding light data. I use a constant to declare the array size, as is good practice. Let's say this variable is declared as

```
const int NUM_POINT_LIGHTS = 100;
```

How can I use C++ to pull this data out of the shader, so that my C++ program knows exactly how many lights it has available to it? I've tried declaring it as

```
const uniform int NUM_POINT_LIGHTS = 100;
```

As expected, this didn't work (though oddly enough, it appears as though the uniform specification simply overrode the const specification, as the OpenGL complained that I was initializing an array with a non-const value). I also tried

```
const int NUM_POINT_LIGHTS = 100;
uniform numPointLights = NUM_POINT_LIGHTS;
```

This would work, except for the fact that GLSL optimizes away unused uniforms so I have to track glsl into thinking the uniform is used somehow in order to be able to get a hold of the data. I've not been able to find any other method to query a program to get a constant value. Does anybody have any ideas how I might be able to pull a constant out of a shader so my program to get information that is functionally encoded in the shader for it's use?

Comment: Generally speaking, constant literals written that way become uniforms after shader compilation. On an NV GLSL implementation that's likely to be called something like `_main_NUM_POINT_LIGHTS`. I would suggest that you enumerate all of the uniforms in your program to see if that happens. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish in the end though... if you want an array of data you'd be better off using a UBO because it's not bound by the same constraints (e.g. maximum number of uniform components) as uniforms.

Comment: I'd assumed that the components of the UBO counted against the maximum number of uniform components, though it was relatively easy to confirm that they didn't by adding an array with a number of elements above my 460m's cap of 2048 uniform components for a fragment shader. I'm actually using a UBO for this, but even when using a UBO it'd be nice to be able to have a c++ program dynamically determine the number of lights it has available to it. I'll look and see what uniforms are created, though this sounds like a solution that may not port to other hardware.

Comment: No such luck, no uniform for my constant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can directly get the value of the constant. However, I figure you must use the value of the constant, most likely as the size of a uniform array. If that's the case, you can get the size of the uniform array, which indirectly gets you the value of the constant.

Say your shader contains something like this:

```
const int NUM_POINT_LIGHTS = 100;
uniform vec3 LightPositions[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];
```

Then you can first get the index of this uniform:

```
const GLchar* uniformName = "LightPositions";
GLuint uniformIdx = 0;
glGetUniformIndices(program, 1, &uniformName, &uniformIdx);
```

Using this index, you can then retrieve attributes of this uniform:

```
const int nameLen = strlen("LightPositions") + 1;
const GLchar name[nameLen];
GLint uniformSize = 0;
GLenum uniformType = GL_NONE;
glGetActiveUniform(program, uniformIdx, nameLen, NULL,
                   &uniformSize, &uniformType, name);
```

`uniformSize` should then be the value of the `NUM_POINT_LIGHTS` constant. Note that I haven't tried this, but I hope I got the arguments right based on the documentation.

A somewhat ugly but possibly very practical solution is of course to parse the value out of the shader source code. Since you need to read it in anyway before passing it to `glShaderSource()`, picking out the constant value should be easy enough.

Yet another option, if your main goal is to avoid having the constant in multiple places, is to define it in your C++ code, and add the constant definition to the shader code dynamically after reading in the shader code, and before passing it go `glShaderSource()`.

Comment: +1 for injecting `#define NUM_POINT_LIGHTS` into the shader source dynamically

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use glGetUniformIndices on an array of structs, as each individual element has it's own index rather than the array having one.

However, either parsing the value out of the source or dynamically adding it to the source would both work as really good ways to make this function. Dynamically adding it in may actually be my best option, as it lets multiple shaders be written with a variable and be consistently kept synchronized with the program capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just query a constant from a GLSL program. No such thing is defined in the GLSL spec.

Uniform Buffer Objects might be a way to get around the issue of uniforms being optimized out. 
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object

Comment: Unfortunately, UBO members cannot have initializers. :(

Comment: I think you're trying to hard too make everything dynamic. You could totally do vendor dependent workarounds or even look at the source code of the shader itself when your read it in but what do you lose form just having the constant defined in C++ also?  Any workarounds are going to be very complex.